# How can I show error message in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show an error message when login failed.

This is my html markup:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="/Login/SignInTeacher" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <img src="~/images/Login4.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-fluid" style="height: 300px;">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email Adresiniz" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="font-size: medium;">
        <br>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Parola" placeholder="Şifreniz" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="font-size: medium;">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success btn-lg">Login</button>
        <br>
        <label style="font-size: medium; margin-left: 0%;">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="/Home/ForgetPassword/">password?</a></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignInTeacher(Teacher t)
{
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

    string willbeEncrypted = s.Parola;
    string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(willbeEncrypted)));

    var info = c.Teachers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == s.Email && x.Parola == encrypted);

    if (info != null)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,s.Email)
            };
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Login");

        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);

        var value = from deger in c.Teachers
                    where deger.Email == s.Email
                    select deger.Email;

        var nameuser = value;
           
        return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home", new { user = nameuser });
    }
        
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

When user logs in successfully, the main page opens; when login fails, the main page does not open return same page (refresh) but I can't show the error message instead of page refresh like this "Username or password is wrong".

I tried it with viewbag but that did not work because this command return `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` prevent the viewbag message.

Comment: Hi @Knadre, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> when login failed main page does not open return same page(refresh) but I cant achieve show the error message instead of page refresh like this "Username or password is wronng".

To achieve your requirement, you can try to pass error message through [`TempData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#tempdata), like below.

```
TempData["ErrorMes"] = "Username or password is wronng";

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

*Display error message in Index page*

```
<span class="text-danger">@TempData["ErrorMes"]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use ModelState.AddModelError like below, it'll return to the same login view with model error and model state will be invalid

Example :

```
if(isLoginSuccess)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
}else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("InvalidLogin", "Invalid Login Attempt");
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```